# Can't plot the complete Cobweb diagram in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I was trying to produce the cobweb diagram of the following equation
xn+1 = xn * e ^ a(1−xn/1000), x0 = 200 and a is a constant 
But somehow I couldn't plot the original function and y = (x)
The following is my code in scilab

```
x0 = 200
n = 20
a = 2
deff("y = F(x)", "y = x*%e^(a*(1-x/1000))")
cw = [x0 0];
x = x0;
for i = 1:n
    newx = F(x);
    cw = [cw;x newx; newx newx];
    x = newx
end
for x = x0;
    y1 = x*%e^(a*(1-x/1000))
    y2 = x
end
plot2d(cw(:,1),cw(:,2),4)
plot2d(x, y1, 5)
plot2d(x, y2, 6)
title("Cobweb Diagram")
xlabel("x(n)")
ylabel("x(n+1)")
```

Comment: Your code runs fine. Your problem tackles with the cobweb methodology and stackoverflow is not the right place to ask about it. See [Computer Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) maybe.

Comment: Thanks. I have already solved the problem, even though I still don't understand what went wrong in my original code.